# Evaluating double integral by change of variables

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I've been looking at similar examples but I still don't understand on how to approach this question.  :(

Evaluate the double integral $\iint_R$  $\sqrt {16x^2 + 9y^2}\, dx \,dy$  by change of variables, where R is the region enclosed by the ellipse $ \frac {x^2} {9} + \frac{y^2}{16} = 1$

Comment: Hint: changing $x=3r \cos t, y=4r \sin t$ should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
  (x,y) &= (3u\cos v, 4u\sin v) \\[4pt]
  \left| \frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)} \right| &=
  \begin{vmatrix}
    3\cos v & -3u\sin v \\
    4\sin v & 4u\cos v
  \end{vmatrix} \\[4pt]
  &= 12u  \\[4pt]
  \sqrt{16x^2+16y} &= 12u \\[4pt]
  \iint_R \sqrt{16x^2+16y} \, dx \, dy &=
  \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1}  12u \times 12u \, du \, dv \\[4pt]
  &= 96\pi
\end{align}